# How the message id is created.How can we remove that field from log

Tags: java, wso2, log4j

I am having some issue with the logging in WSO2.
I want to create logs in wso2 and tried but getting output like below..

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-08-01 18:40:53,094]  INFO 
{org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -To:, WSAction:urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, 
MessageID: ID:D-113090917-60191-1500010242277-4:28:1:1:1,Direction: request,
Date and Time=2017-08-01 18:40:53.009 IST, Event Name=demo Event, APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER = 0.0.0-RC1, 
APPLICATION_ADDRESS = 10.113.175.116, GEO_LOCATION = India, CODE_LOCATION = Demo_process_seq, 
USER_IDENTITY = xyz, DESTINATION = abc, MESSAGE_IDENTIFIER = FMP-3335197, 
MESSAGE_TYPE = MT564, DESCRIPTION = messages received... {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

I dont want to print the initial fields like the field from -To: until  MessageID..

Because they are unnecessary for me

Also I just want to print values not key value pair like I am getting

Date and Time=2017-08-01 18:40:53.009 IST but I only want the value of that field.

Please help me to get correct output if somebody is known to this.
Thanks in advance

The code I am using is as below:

```
<call-template    target="gov:/cs_as/common/utils/template/cs_as_standard_logging_st.xml">
      <with-param xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                  name="WST_Date"
                  value="{get-property('WST_Date_Time')}"/>
      <with-param xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                  name="WST_Event_Name"
                  value="{get-property('WST_Event_Name')}"/>
      <with-param xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                  name="WST_APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER"
                  value="{get-property('WST_APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER')}"/>

      <with-param xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                  name="WST_APPLICATION_ADDRESS "
                  value="{get-property('WST_APPLICATION_ADDRESS')}"/>
<with-param xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                  name="WST_GEO_LOCATION"
                  value="{get-property('WST_GEO_LOCATION')}"/>
<with-param xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                  name="WST_CODE_LOCATION"
                  value="{get-property('WST_CODE_LOCATION')}"/>
<with-param xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                  name="WST_USER_IDENTITY"
                  value="{get-property('WST_USER_IDENTITY')}"/>
<with-param xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                  name="WST_DESTINATION"
                  value="{get-property('WST_DESTINATION')}"/>
<with-param xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                  name="WST_MESSAGE_IDENTIFIER"
                  value="{get-property('WST_MESSAGE_IDENTIFIER')}"/>
<with-param xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                  name="WST_MESSAGE_TYPE"
                  value="{get-property('WST_MESSAGE_TYPE')}"/>
<with-param xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                  name="WST_DESCRIPTION"
                  value="{get-property('WST_DESCRIPTION')}"/>

      <with-param name="WST_CATEGORY" value="INFO"/>
      <with-param name="WST_LEVEL" value="Full"/>
      <with-param name="WST_DROP_YN" value="N"/>
   </call-template>
```

Comment: Can you show the code using which you are generating this log statement?

Comment: I am using the property mediator for setting all the properties I want to print in the log and then I am using call-template for getting logs